# Are declared property attributes overridden when implementing custom accessor methods?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, declared-property

Suppose I declare a property like so

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSObject *property;
```

Then I create a custom setter method

```
- (void) setProperty:(NSObject *)property
{
    _property = property;

    // Some more code here
}
```

Does the compiler interpret the `copy` keyword so that this setter function is equivalent to this?

```
_property = [property copy];
```

Or is it my responsibility to write it this way so that the keyword matches the behavior?

Comment: it is your responsibility in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "4.1.1 Property declarations" in the [Clang/ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)
(emphasis added):

> - `copy` implies `__strong` ownership, as well as the usual behavior of copy semantics on the setter.
> - ...
>
> A property’s specified ownership is preserved in its metadata, but
>   otherwise the meaning is **purely conventional unless the property is
>   synthesized**.
>   If a property is synthesized, then the associated instance variable is
>   the instance variable which is named, possibly implicitly, by the
>   @synthesize declaration. If the associated instance variable already
>   exists, then its ownership qualification must equal the ownership of
>   the property; otherwise, the instance variable is created with that
>   ownership qualification.

So in your case, with a custom setter, declaring the property as "copy" implies that the associated
instance variable `_property` is `__strong` but nothing else.

It is your responsibility that the setter actually makes a copy, for example:

```
- (void) setProperty:(NSObject *)property
{
    _property = [property copy];
    // Some more code here
}
```